# Determine if a property is a collection or not with SpringDataRest schema

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm building a client/code generator that dynamically adapts to a spring data rest endpoint.

I'm asking for schema information with two requests:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/schema+json" http://localhost:8080/legalEntity
curl -v -H "Accept: application/hal+json" http://localhost:8080/legalEntity
```

This gives me the schema of an `ApiLegalEntity`. Particularly, I'm interested in one of the child properties of this entity, which I know is  a `List<ApiAccount>`. For schema, I get:

```
{
  "title": "Api legal entity",
  "properties": {
    "accounts": {
      "title": "Accounts",
      "readOnly": true,
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uri"
    },
    ...
  },
  "definitions": {},
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
}
```

So far, I have no way of deciphering anything much other than the property name, but fortunately hal tells me (almost) everything else:

```
{
  "alps": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "descriptors": [
      {
        "id": "legalentities-representation",
        "href": "http://.../profile/legalentities",
        ...
        "descriptors": [
          {
            "name": "accounts",
            "type": "SAFE",
            "rt": "http://.../#accounts-representation"
          },
          ...
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "get-legalentities",
       ...
      },
     ]
  }
}
```

Great! now from the `"rt": "http://.../#accounts-representation"` I know that the `accounts` property is an `ApiAccount` entity. Now, how do I tell that it's a collection of ApiAccounts?